# Detect switching between 2 instances of UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that derives from `UserControl` (below). The user can have more than one instance of this control open at a time.
I want to be able to detect when the user switches from one to the other, i.e. has clicked on one and then clicks on another.

`OnEnter` and `OnLoad` get called only when first displaying the control
`OnLeave` is never called.
`OnGotFocus` and `OnLostFocus` are never called but apparently their use is discouraged.
What do I need to do?

```
 public partial class MyView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
 {
         // Before `OnLoad`
         // WM_NCCREATE, WM_NCCALCSIZE WM_CREATE, WM_SIZE, WM_MOVE,WM_REFLECT, WM_SHOWWINDOW, WM_PARENTNOTIFY
         // After `OnLoad`, Before `OnEnter`
         // WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, WM_NCCALCSIZE, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, WM_SIZE, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, WM_GETTEXT, (WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, WM_NCCALCSIZE, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, WM_SIZE, WM_CHILDACTIVATE, WM_MOVE, WM_SHOWWINDOW
        private const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x006;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            if (message.Msg == WM_ACTIVATE)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyView.WndProc(): message: " + message);
            }
            base.WndProc(ref message);
        }

        // called before OnEnter
        protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnLoad(eventArgs);

            Form form1 = this.FindForm();      // null
            Form parentForm = this.ParentForm; // null
        }

        // called only on first display, not when the user switches between the 2 controls
        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnEnter(eventArgs);
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnLeave(eventArgs);
        }

        // Never called
        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(eventArgs);
        }

        // Never called
        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(eventArgs);
        }
 }
```

Comment: `OnEnter` is called when the users *Tabs* or clicks inside a UserControl. The click will  cause a call to `OnEnter` if the UC or a selectable child control is clicked: won't be called if the user clicks on a Label, for example. Tabbing into the UC (having `TabStop` set to `true`) always calls `OnEnter`, even if the UC doesn't have any focusable controls.

Comment: The same goes for `OnLeave`. The user needs to Tab/Click on a focusable object for the UC to raise the `Leave` event.

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks for your comments. I'm not experiencing this, i.e. when a selectable child control (e.g. a TextBox) in the `UserControl` is clicked, the `OnEnter` event is not called.

Comment: This is simply not possible. Not with the code you're showing here. Both `OnEnter` and `OnLeave` will be called. Not a supposition (though this behaviour is well known): I pasted your code into a new UserControl and tested it. Do the same.

Comment: I saw *(...) the GUI component itself does not have a parent* comment: this is also not possible, a UC must to have a Parent, the Form where it's shown. It can't live on its own. Your context is not that clear. Are you using some sort of MV** pattern (the name `MyView` suggests this)?

Comment: "Both OnEnter and OnLeave will be called". I think I see an issue. This `UserControl` has 2 children, a `Panel` and a `ToolStrip`. Those 2, in turn, have numerous children. So I need to have `OnEnter` and `OnLeave` for the 2 children, and then grandchildren, and so on. Is this possible? (without explicitly defining for each).

Comment: No problems with the ToolStrip: all children will call `OnEnter`. If you want the Panel to also call `OnEnter` when clicked/focused, you need a custom Panel. In the custom Panel's constructor add: `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse | ControlStyles.Selectable, true);`. This way, the Panel will be clickable and selectable, thus will call `OnEnter`/ raise the `Enter` event. As already said, *tabbing* into the UC will call `OnEnter` in any case.

Comment: @Jimi: "This is simply not possible". When I do `Form form1 = this.FindForm();` and `Form parentForm = this.ParentForm;` in `OnLoad`, both values are null. Fwiw, I did not write this code. It is old code (at least 10 years old) that I've inherited.

Comment: Have you called `base.OnLoad(e);` before that? `FindForm()` will return the Form instance that created the UC even if you create the UC in code (in the Form costructor, `Load` event or anywhere else, if the form has already an Handle).

Comment: The call to `base.OnLoad();` is in `MyView.OnLoad`. I've edited the code in the question to show the lines for `form1` and `parentForm`, which follow this call, and the values are  null. `base.GetType()` return `MyView` fwiw.

Comment: The UC's `OnLoad` is called when the hosting Form is shown. When/where/how are you creating this UC? Are you adding it to a Form (`[Form.Controls.Add([MyUSerControl])]`)? Is the Form shown at some point? Are you using a Controller, by chance?

Comment: Yes, it is using a Controller.

Comment: There you have it. That's the part you have to fix, not the UC itself.

Comment: So I need to handle `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` in the Controller?

Comment: `Enter` and `Leave`. But I know nothing about your concrete implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete source code the for the user derived control. It works as is.

On the form, I created two instances of the control and can click on them. As I do, the squares switch from red to blue.

You should be able to set breakpoints in the OnGotFocus and OnLostFocus methods. The invalidates are there to force a repaint.

The magic is that there are two controls (as you have also) but in addition, the OnButtonclicked override sets the focus. I believe this is the part that's missing from your example.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DesktopApp1
{
    public partial class MyView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {

        protected Color SelectedColor { get; set; } = Color.Red;
        protected Color NormalColor { get; set; } = Color.Blue;
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(this.Focused?SelectedColor:NormalColor))
            using (Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, ClientRectangle);

                Rectangle inset = new Rectangle(this.ClientRectangle.X + 1, this.ClientRectangle.Y + 1, this.ClientRectangle.Width -3 , this.ClientRectangle.Height - 3);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, inset);
            }
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        private void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Select();
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

To complete the answer here is the form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace DesktopApp1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.myView2 = new DesktopApp1.MyView();
            this.myView1 = new DesktopApp1.MyView();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // myView2
            // 
            this.myView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(189, 12);
            this.myView2.Name = "myView2";
            this.myView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
            this.myView2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // myView1
            // 
            this.myView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 12);
            this.myView1.Name = "myView1";
            this.myView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
            this.myView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(355, 175);
            this.Controls.Add(this.myView2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.myView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private MyView myView1;
        private MyView myView2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You refer to "OnButtonClicked override" in your comment and `OnButton1Clicked` is in the code. I will assume the code should be `OnButtonClicked`. And the method in the code does not override anything, nor do I see that there is a `OnButtonClicked` method to override for `UserControl`. Also, as I said in the question, `OnGotFocus` and `OnLostFocus` are never called but apparently their use is discouraged anyway.

Comment: @AlLelopath I believe that if you start with a blank windows forms project and use the source provided that it will work. If it does not then I don't know how to help with out more information. If it does then you can use this as a base and add code from your project a little at a time to find out where the point of pain lay.

Comment: @AlLelopath, Also using On(Lost|Gain)Focus use is valid for detecting the change in focus. The general admonishment against such use is related to altering the focus. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.ongotfocus?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_OnGotFocus_System_EventArgs_

Answer (score 1):

Requirement: "I want to be able to detect when the operator ...has clicked on one and then clicks on another."

Apparently you want to get notified if the control is clicked, or on any of its child controls. For this you'll have to subscribe to the Click events of all your child controls.

```
protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
{
     // subscribe to click event of e.Control
     e.Control.Click += OnChildClicked;
}
// TODO: de-subscribe in OnControlRemoved

public void OnChildClicked(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clicked on child control, act as if Clicked on me
    this.OnClick(e);
}
```

The click event will be called by any click-like event, even if it is done by the keyboard, for instance by pressing the enter key.

You wrote you wanted mouse clicks. If you really want only mouse clicks, use the MouseClick event. If an operator uses TAB to select one of your child controls and presses ENTER to click it, you won't get notified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this code. The `OnChildClicked` is never called. I failed to mention that this class is not a child of anything which may be the reason for this.

Comment: Sigh! Please get your questions right. You wrote: "I have a class that derives from `UserControl`".What is it: is your class derived from `UserControl` or not? I tried it and it works.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. It does derive from `UserControl`. I think there are conceptually 2 different parent/child relationships here. One relationship is that this class does indeed derive from `UserControl` (as shown in the code). The other is that the GUI component itself does not have a parent. For example, if in the `OnChildClicked` method, I were to add the line `base.OnClick(e);`, this would result in an infinite loop because `base` here would be the same as `this`. I hope I am being clear.

Comment: I think I see an issue. This UserControl has 2 children, a Panel and a ToolStrip. Those 2, in turn, have numerous children. So I need to have `OnChildClicked` that is called for the 2 children, and the grandchildren, and so on. Is this possible?